# Error handling using controller in grails

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I have an error.gsp file that handles errors. I want to add server logic to the errors behaviour so I changed my mappings
from: `"500"(view: '/error')`
to: `"500"(controller: 'errors')`
in my UrlMappings class.

And added a new controller:

```
class ErrorsController {
    def index() {
        println(request.exception)
        render view: '/error'
    }
}
```

I need the exception data and it is NULL, yet it exists in the view.
The model is also null.

How can I get the exception object in the errors controller?

Regards, Ido

Comment: what grails version do you use?

Comment: I use grails version 3.0.17

Comment: your code should work. Are you sure that index action gets called?

Comment: Yes. I find myself eventually in the view where i do have the exception